# User rolled-back my approved edit (OP answered in question)

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Can someone please roll back to my edit (revision 4) on [pip upgrade throws 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060525/pip-upgrade-throws-typeerror-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object)? I don't want to get into an edit-rollback war, but I believe my edit was justified.

The edit was approved by the community. My goal was primarily to take the answer out of the question, and I made some adjustments to the tags to make it easier to find and made small changes to the grammar.

Also, please let me know if I've done something wrong here as directly as you can. I find criticism "welcoming".

Comment: It seems the OP saw your answer/comment after rolling back the edit and they acknowledged the fact that the answer should be in the answers section so posted an answer. So I rolled it back to your version.

Comment: I think that rollback was an accident.. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @user2285236 I think that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @user202729 for a moment there I thought you're commenting to yourself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was a mistake by a confusing UI. When someone suggest an edit to our post the author is left with a message that links to the edit and a single button asking for action. Now the author is left with one option: to click the button. I would like that the UI would be like the review instead, with two options.

Comment: Clearly they overlooked the notice "This suggested edit to your post has already been reviewed and your action is no longer required."

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296170/292385)

Comment: Better yet, have no options at all on a *notification* page. Make the user go somewhere else to rollback the edit. E.g., "Visit this page if you disagree with this edit," with "this page" being a link to the revision history.

Comment: UI is clear, instructions provided. Improving UI in this case leads to less functional design for the sake of usertype who "see's single button infers action is required"

Comment: @AnonymousType [I push all buttons I see my way](https://xkcd.com/627/), you don't?

Comment: Yes, @gparyani, likely they did overlook the notice.  Or else they did not carefully read the label on the button before clicking it.  Notification dialogs with a single "OK" button are pretty common, so it is not so surprising that an insufficiently attentive user seeing just one button might take it for a "make this notification go away" control.  I'm inclined to agree, therefore, that the UI is confusing.  That the user *could have* known what they were expected to do does not change that.